# Modify pre-existing IAM roles using terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I want to start managing the policies on pre-existing IAM roles using terraform. I have many IAM roles with policies attached to them in AWS account. These roles were created manually via the console. Now i want to start managing them using terraform. What is the best way to do this? Thanks, Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

1. Create those roles in Terraform
2. [Import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) those roles into your Terraform state
3. Run terraform plan until it returns no changes
4. Commit to source control

Keep doing that cycle until everything has been migrated over.

Comment: Thank You @Jamie, i have created a resource in the root directory that i want to import. `resource "aws_iam_role" "test-role" {
  provider = "aws.test"
  name     = "aws@test-role"
}` however, when i run `terraform import aws_iam_role.test-role aws@test-role` i am getting **Terraform detected a resource with this ID doesn't
exist**. any idea what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: I was able to successfuly import the role. i had to fix my provider to get to role ARN properly